# Network Link Conditioner can not work together with Reachability?

Tags: ios5, afnetworking, reachability

Network Link Conditioner is the develop tool provided by Apple, but seem like not work together with the other tool Reachability.

Network Link Conditioner is the tool to simulate 3G/Edge/Wifi network cases.
Reachability is to recognize the different network cases.

Anyone has such experience to make them work together ?

Comment: your question is not very clear:  how do they not work well together?  What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have any issue with Reachability since it really just tells you whether or not you have a network connection, not how well it is functioning. The only difference is between Wifi and Cellular, not between different speeds or cellular connections.

Answer (score 0):

Reachability doesn't test the speed of the network to determine what kind it is. Reachability is about availability of interfaces (airplane mode vs. not, wifi on / off).

Important note:

> A remote host is considered reachable when a data packet, sent by an application into the network stack, can leave the local device. Reachability does not guarantee that the data packet will actually be received by the host.

From Apple's [SCNetworkReachability](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SystemConfiguration/Reference/SCNetworkReachabilityRef/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007260) documentation.